# Android Preferred Network List

Tags: android, wifimanager, wifi

I was under the impression that `wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()` returns the PNL of the current device, however when I click on - forget network, `wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()` still keeps that network but just removes the connection details(like security, password etc.) 
Is there anyway knowing which SSID(or BSSID) is actually in PNL? (i.e my device can automatically connect to it)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this problem appeared only on specifics networks, while in others clicking on forget network actually removes the network from `wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()`.

I also found out that the only things different are `allowedKeyManagement.cardinality` and `LinkProperties` (which is hidden on Android), so I used an if statement on the `WifiConfiguration`(=configuredNetwork):

```
if(configuredNetwork.allowedKeyManagement.cardinality()==1)
   wifiManager.removeNetwork(configuredNetwork.networkId);
   wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
   break;
```

And for some reason it worked. If anyone have an idea whats cardinality stands for or have a better way of doing this please share.